# Why Generic method for delegate events not working with error message Method name expected

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

Work on C#.

**My delegate and events are bellow**

```
 #region delegate event

        #region 
        public delegate void NotifynextDeviceReceivedDelegate(CustomEventArgs customEventArgs);
        public event NotifynextDeviceReceivedDelegate NotifynextDeviceReceivedEvent;
        #endregion

        #region 
        public delegate void NotifynextDeviceedDelegate(CustomEventArgs customEventArgs);
        public event NotifynextDeviceedDelegate NotifynextDeviceedEvent;
        #endregion

        #region 
        public delegate void NotifynextReceiveddDelegate(CustomEventArgs customEventArgs);
        public event NotifynextReceiveddDelegate NotifynextReceiveddEvent;
        #endregion

        #endregion
```

**To invoke i used bellow syntax it's work perfectly**

```
              if (NotifynextDeviceReceivedEvent != null)
                    {
                        CustomEventArgs customEventArgs = new CustomEventArgs(receivedMessage, receivedTopic);
                        //Raise Event. All the listeners of this event will get a call.
                        NotifynextDeviceReceivedEvent(customEventArgs);
                     }
```

**Need to write same above syntax for all of the event delegate.So,i decided to write generic event to invoke them like bellow:**

```
     InvokeEvents<NotifynextDeviceReceivedDelegate>(receivedMessage,receivedTopic,NotifynextDeviceReceivedEvent)


        public static InvokeEvents<T>(string receivedMessage,string receivedTopic, T notifynextDeviceReceivedEvent)
            {

                    if (notifynextDeviceReceivedEvent != null)
                    {
                        CustomEventArgs customEventArgs = new CustomEventArgs(receivedMessage, receivedTopic);

                        notifynextDeviceReceivedEvent(customEventArgs);//here is the problem show me error message
                    }

            }
```

In **InvokeEvents** method why notifynextDeviceReceivedEvent show me error **Method name expected**

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful here, so that we could copy/paste your code into an IDE and see exactly the same error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your code as this:

```
private static void InvokeEvents<T>(string receivedMessage, string receivedTopic, T eventDelegate)
{
    if (eventDelegate != null)
    {
        var customEventArgs = new CustomEventArgs(receivedMessage, receivedTopic);
        ((Delegate)(object)eventDelegate).DynamicInvoke(customEventArgs);
    }
}
```

This works. I tested it.

You do require the double cast to make the compiler happy.

There's also no point in making the accessor `public` as you can't pass a event delegate to it from anywhere outside of the class.

So, since you can't all this code from outside your class, you then must write code within your class to call `InvokeEvents`, like this:

```
public void OnNotifynextDeviceedEvent()
{
    InvokeEvents("", "", this.NotifynextDeviceedEvent);
}
```

Which really then means you could have to repeat code in any case.

Now, with C# 6's syntax then you can write these methods as this:

```
public void OnNotifynextDeviceedEvent()
    => this.NotifynextDeviceedEvent?.Invoke(new CustomEventArgs("", ""));
```

So you're really not saving much code - none in fact - and you're creating a weakly-typed method. You really should stick with the basic approach.